# Determining mininium files required for dojo widget

Tags: dojo

First off, I'm brand new to Dojo.

I'm integrating it into our existing web app.
We initially only need the [Calendar](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojox/calendar.html) widget functionality.

I'm looking to keep the number and size of files as small as possible.

I don't believe downloading just the base code file will be sufficent?
http://dojotoolkit.org/download/

Additionally, the Dojo toolkit download is a huge zip (Even if I was to only use compressed files)
Am I left with downloading the toolkit and manually removing everything I don't need?

Is there no custom download builder like [jquery ui](http://jqueryui.com/download/)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the dojo library is much larger than jquery ui and I don't know of an equivalent to the download builder. If you are just interested in using dojo for a single widget, you might consider exploring a different library.

To use dojox/Calendar, you are still going to need the many dependencies it has on other dojo modules. You can do this manually, but it will be tedious.

One thing you can do is run dojo's build system to package dojox/Calendar and all of its dependencies into a single file. This isn't a trivial task and requires a good understanding of dojo's AMD loader and package system.

If you want to go down this route, I would clone the [dojo-boilerplate](https://github.com/csnover/dojo-boilerplate) project on github. It contains everything you need to do this out of the box. Then follow the [build system tutorial](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.9/build/) to understand how you set this up. From there you can have your app depend on dojox/Calendar to produce the file you include on your page to consume it.

Comment: Unfortunately Dojo appears to be the only open source framework that gives me the required Calendar Widget functionality I need. I'll look into your suggestion as well as Dariens. Thanks Kryptic.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest that you put the *whole* thing (yes, it's a lot of tiny files) to your server.

Dojo 1.9 is written so that when users visit, their computers will only download the individual pieces on an *as-needed* basis. This is possible because every piece (AMD modules) is explicit about what it needs.

Once you have something that works, you can choose speed-up loading times by using the [build system](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.9/build/). Basically, this involves going: "If the user wants *this thing*, they'll probably want all this *other* stuff, so create a big minified lump and give it to them whenever they start asking." Best of all, it doesn't have to be perfect: If you miss including something, the users browser will still request it *a la carte*.

At work we're using the [Dojo Boilerplate](https://github.com/csnover/dojo-boilerplate) starting application which helps give some initial organization to the build process.

Comment: Thanks Darien, I'll look into this solution as well as Kryptic's one.